# LotusScript export to Excel from NotesDocumentCollection

Tags: excel, lotusscript

I need export to Excel documents between two dates from view.
I created NotesDocumentCollection based on NotesDateRange.

I've problem with:

```
ForAll colval In doc.Columnvalues
```

It's works fine when doc is from NotesView but I need documents between two dates so doc is from NotesDocumentCollecion and then I get "Type mismatch" error.

Piece of code with doc from NotesView  which work's fine:

```
Set doc = view.Getfirstdocument()
row% = 0
While Not doc Is Nothing
    row% = row% + 1
    col% = 0 'Reset the columns
    ForAll  colval In doc.Columnvalues
        col% = col% + 1
        xlSheet.Cells(row%,col%).value = colval
    End ForAll
Set doc = view.Getnextdocument(doc)
Wend`
```

Piece of code with doc from NotesDocumentCollection where I get "Type mismatch" error in ForAll line:

```
Set doc = dc.Getfirstdocument()
row% = 0
While Not doc Is Nothing
    row% = row% + 1
    col% = 0 'Reset the columns
    ForAll  colval In doc.Columnvalues
        col% = col% + 1
        xlSheet.Cells(row%,col%).value = colval
    End ForAll
Set doc = dc.Getnextdocument(doc)
Wend`
```

Does anyone know how to export to Excel from NotesDocumentCollection ?

Answer (score 0):

A document collection has no columns.  It's a collection of documents, so your forall makes no sense.  You can't access document fields as an ordinal like you're trying to do.  You need to know the names of the fields that each of the columns refer to, or if the column is a formula, compute it yourself.  For example:

```
xSheet.Cells(row,1).value = doc.firstname(0)
xSheet.Cells(row,2).value = doc.lastname(0)
```

One option could be to set up an array of field names.  For example:

```
dim fieldnames(10) as string
fieldnames(0) = "firstname"
fieldnames(1) = "lastname"
' etc.
```

That would allow you do do something like:

```
for I = 0 to ubound(fieldnames)
    xlSheet.Cells(row, I) = doc.getItemValue(fieldnames(I))
next I
```

Comment: "A document collection has no columns" - it does if the collection was gained from a view eg view.getalldocumentsbykey

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now I realize that document collection has no columns. 

It has to be a document collection because I need documents based on date range. 

What do you think about another approach to solve this problem:

1. Get first document collection based on date range. 
2. In "while not doc Is Nothing" loop:
    get UNID of this document,
    get tempDoc byKey(UNID) from view which first column is UNID,
    In forall loop get all columnvalues from tempDoc,
    get next doc from document collection.
3. At the end sort xls sheet by chosen column.

Comment: I suppose you could do it that way, but it sounds complicated and has the potential to be a performance pig.  Frankly, if it were me, I'd add computed fields to the form itself.  Then the formulae for the computed fields would be the formulas you'd use in the view columns (and optionally you can change your view to use the computed fields as well.)  That way it's a simple matter to get your document collection and the data you want without having to do extra lookups.

Answer (score -1):

Help for Columnvalues:
"Read-only. An array of values, each element of which corresponds to a column value in the document's parent view. The first value in the array is the value that appears in the view's first column for the document, the second value is the one that appears in the second column, and so on. The value of each element of the array is the result of the corresponding column's formula and the items on the current document. Some elements in the array might have no value.

If you do not access the document through a view, this property has no value."

doc.Columnvalues *IS* available on documents in a notesdocumentcollection, but only if that collection was populated via a view eg using view.getalldocumentsbykey().

So there'sw not quite enough info in your question:  How are you getting the document collection ? If it's an FTSearch then that wouldn't involve a view, so no columnvalues would exist